# Struts2 -- NullPointerException from radio button

Tags: struts2, radio-button, nullpointerexception

I have the following form in a Struts2 JSP that contains some radio buttons.  There are 2 other forms on the page that work correctly, but this one doesn't.  I have determined that the value selected is somehow not being passed, and that that is the reason I'm getting a NullPointerException, but I can't figure out why it's happening.  Can anyone help me?  Here is my JSP form.

```
            <s:form action="ProcessPoll3">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b><i>Poll #3</i></b></td>
                        <td>How many kids do you have?</td>
                        <td><s:radio name="poll3"
                            list="#{'1':'0.', '2':'1.', '3':'2.', 
                                    '4':'3.', '5':'More than 3.'}" />
                        <s:submit value="Vote Poll #3" align="left" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </s:form>
```

My DAO class gets called with this line (and it is being called, for sure):
    String poll3;
    private HttpServletResponse response;

```
public String getPoll3() {
    return poll3;
}

public void setPoll2(String poll3) {
    this.poll3 = poll3;
}

public String execute() {
        Poll3DAO poll3DAO = new Poll3DAO();

        if (poll3DAO.tallyVote(poll3).equals("success")) {
           // Processing goes on here, not relevant to this problem
        }
```

Here is the method in the DAO class, with the breakdown point marked because the parameter that was supposed to be passed was null.

```
public String tallyVote(String vote) {
    String successfulWrite;
    request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) request.getSession()
            .getServletContext().getAttribute("sessionFactory");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        // Get previous results
        Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
        Query myQuery = session.createQuery("from Poll3");
        tx1.commit();

        // Update results
        Iterator<Poll3> iterate = myQuery.iterate();
        Poll3 poll3 = iterate.next();
        // NullPointerException occurs on next line
        if (vote.equals("1")) {
            poll3.setZero(poll3.getZero() + 1);
        } else if (vote.equals("2")) {
            poll3.setOne(poll3.getOne() + 1);
        } else if (vote.equals("3")) {
            poll3.setTwo(poll3.getTwo() + 1);
        } else if (vote.equals("4")) {
            poll3.setThree(poll3.getThree() + 1);
        } else if (vote.equals("5")) {
            poll3.setMoreThanThree(poll3.getMoreThanThree() + 1);
        }

        // Write new results back to database;
        Transaction tx2 = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(poll3);
        tx2.commit();
        successfulWrite = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        successfulWrite = "failure";
    }

    return successfulWrite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting it's this:

```
public void setPoll2(String poll3) { ... }
```

This is why we have map/collection support to avoid writing cut-and-paste blobs like this.

*Any* time you find yourself cutting and pasting code like in your snippets it's generally because an abstraction has been ignored/overlooked.

Comment: Ah yes, it had to be something right under my nose, something so obvious I couldn't see it.  Thank you, Dave.  This is exactly what the problem was.  Thank you for having better eyes than I do.  :-)

Comment: @Frank Easier when you haven't been staring at it ;)